# how to maintain button image state in tableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have one table view and each cell has one button after pressing button, button image got change but if I scroll tableview then button image comes in previous state how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Store in an Array the state of the button, and when the cell is being loaded, check the state for that cell in the array and set the button properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its reloading problem.So my suggestion is

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if(cell == nil){
.................
 alloc your button and give him a tag

 [cell.contentview addSubview yourbutton];
.................
}
yourbutton = (uibutton*)[cell.contentview viewwithtag:buttontag];

if(indexPath.row == your expected index && buttonchangedBolean == YES){

yourbutton.backgroundimage = [uiimage imagenamed:@"imagename.png"];
 }
```

If you do not understand then knock me without any hesitate it is only a suggestion to you. I can give you a solution if you post the code.Whatever try my current suggestion may it will help you.